# Executing an SSH comand on a remote server in php

Tags: php, ssh, exec

I am trying to execute a ssh command on server B machine from Server A with php.I cannot install PHP SSH2 on server A so i will have to reply on exec here

```
exec("ssh root@104.131.126.189 uptime")
```

I want to fully automate the command above but how can i add the password in the command itself.

There is also `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?` prompt where i want to automate the yes input

Comment: You should not login as root over ssh; instead you should disable root login over ssh and use a normal user. And you could install your public key on the server so that you will be authenticated automatically.

Comment: You can use [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) it is written in PHP, no need to install an extension. Regardless of that I would suggest to use key based authentication.